# Perlのpack関数について

Tags: javascript, perl

#### 前提・実現したいこと

今回実現したい事は、Perlのpack関数を
javascript(最終目標:node.jsモジュール)で実現させたいです。

ただperlは全くの素人で、pack自体の挙動は調べた限りの知識しかありません。
仕様として、テンプレとリストがあり、それを用いて各処理が実行される程度…。

一応個人でも、色々調べてみましたが、試した結果は期待通りにならず、難航しております。
ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、お知恵をお貸し頂けますでしょうか。

特に、絞って欲しい情報としては、「C,H*,N」の3つです。

最低でも、アルゴリズムなどが分かれば良いのですが…ご存知に方からの情報をお待ちしております。

補足:
私の知識レベルは、自作でnode.jsのモジュールの追加、作成が可能です。

Comment: 実際に試した（JavaScriptの）コードなどがあれば一緒に提示しておくとアドバイスが付きやすいのではないかと思います。

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44005908/javascript-perl-pack

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605108/pack-unpack-functions-for-node-js

Comment: cubickさんコメントありがとうございます。サンプルコードについては、特に意味を持たないものなで、記載を控えさせて頂きました。

Comment: ernixさん こちらは私が本投稿を英文に訳した同一の質問となります。なお、現在実際に記載されてるコードをnode.jsのモジュールに変換して、挙動の確認を行ってる最中です。 実行結果に問題が無ければ、公開させて頂きます。

Comment: yyzさん ご回答ありがとうございます。本件の内容は、既に実行しており、期待結果と挙動が異なってました。

Comment: [javascript Perl pack [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44006626/7975508)
低評価ですが、こちらの回答頂いた内容にて、解決しました。